# Should we update Twitter feed when a bounty is started

Tags: feature-request, twitter, bounty

Bounties are started when a question has not received enough attention.

Then why not updating the Twitter feed when a question is offered a bounty ?

It could contain a **#bounty** hashtag to draw more attention.